# how to delete all English words, except special punctuation, in R

Tags: regex, r, text-mining, data-cleaning

I have a data file in R,

```
data <- "conflict need resolved :<  turned conversation exchange ideas richer environment one tricky concepts :D    conflict  always top business agendas :>  maybe different ideas opinions different :)"
```

from this I want to remove all words, only the smiles will be there, and the output I am expecting,

```
":< :D :> :)"
```

Is there any library or method in R for doing this task easily?

Comment: Look here: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/qdap/html/rm_stopwords.html -- an alternative solution is to keep only the special characters.

Comment: Thanks Timothee Poisot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[[:alnum:]]` as a regexp pattern for all numeric and alphanumeric characters of a string

```
s <- gsub("[[:alnum:]]*", "", "conflict need resolved :<  turned conversation exchange ideas richer environment one tricky concepts :D    conflict  always top business agendas :>  maybe different ideas opinions different :) ")
gsub(" +", " ", s)

[1] " :< : :> :) "
```

Comment: Or just `'[a-z]'`, which keeps the `D` in `:D`, as long as there aren't any other capitals.

Comment: Thank you very much @HubertL, problem solved. `stri_replace_all_regex(data,"[[:alnum:]]", "", vectorize_all = F)`

Comment: `[:alnum:]` is better, `[a-z]` is  generating some noise in data.